# What is a synonym for the idiom: to make an omelette you have to crack a few eggs?

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there another idiom that conveys the same idea as "to make an omelette you have to crack a few eggs"?

Comment: "there are always casualties in war"?

Comment: Why do you want another idiom? In what context do you plan to use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no information has been given about why the original idiom was unsuitable, or what qualities a similar idiom needs to satisfy.

Comment: It needs to "convey the same idea" - like i said in the original post. I never said it was "unsuitable". I asked whether there is another idiom that conveys the same idea.

Answer (score 4):

A proverb you don't hear much any more but I think is still pertinent:

> *Catus amat piscem, sed non vult tingere plantas.*

("The cat would love to eat fish, but hates to get her feet wet")

Answer (score 3):

Let me start with the meaning of "*to make an omelette you have to crack a few eggs*".

The closest I found in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you%27ve_got_to_crack_a_few_eggs_to_make_an_omelette) is "*you've got to crack a few eggs to make an omelette*".

> *Alternative forms*:  you can't make an omelette without breaking eggs
>
> *Proverb*
>
> **you've got to crack a few eggs to make an omelette**
>
> In order to achieve something, it is inevitable and necessary that
> something be destroyed.

Idiomatically something (few eggs) must be destroyed/sacrificed if you want to achieve something else (make an omelette).

Then the closest (different) idiom I can think of is "***You cannot have your cake and eat it too.***".

Here, you have to ***destroy*** the cake to achieve the ***eating*** of it.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_one%27s_cake_and_eat_it_too):

> *Verb*
> **have one's cake and eat it too**
>
> (*idiomatic*) To seek to have two things which are mutually
> incompatible (such as eating a piece of cake and yet still possessing
> that piece for future use).
>
> It's not possible to get your savings and keep the piggy bank intact.
> You can't have your cake and eat it too!
>
> Usage notes: This expression is found almost exclusively in some form
> of the saying or proverb: **You cannot have your cake and eat it
> too**.

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of [**no pain, no gain.**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_pain,_no_gain)

> [**no pain, no
>   gain**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_pain,_no_gain): an exercise
>   motto that promises greater value rewards for the price of hard and
>   even painful work. Under this conception, competitive professionals,
>   such as athletes and artists, are required to endure pain and pressure
>   to achieve professional excellence.

In other words, you can't make an omelet (a competitive professional) with breaking a few eggs (busting your ass).

Comment: or "nothing ventured, nothing gained"

Answer (score 1):

Not idioms but quotations, which might be helpful:

“You can have anything in life, if you will sacrifice everything else for it.”
― J.M. Barrie, *Peter Pan*

“You can't win a marathon without putting some Band-Aids on your nipples.”
― Dave Harken, *Horrible Bosses*

(People say "All's fair in love and war", but they are generally referring to an action which is unethical as well as destructive.)