# What’s the English for “Let Samson die with all the Philistines”

Tags: idiom-requests

The Book of the Judges (16:18-21; 28-30) tells the story of Samson, an Israelite judge who performed feats of strength against the Philistines but was betrayed by Delilah, his mistress. Blinded by revenge, Samson decided to destroy Philistines temple with his bare hands, although he knew he would die too.

The Italian idiom “Muoia Sansone con tutti i Filistei” (Let Samson die with all the Philistines) is often used in reference to people  who, in order hurt  their rivals or enemies, don’t hesitate to harm themselves too.

What’s the equivalent idiomatic expression in English? (I couldn't find any suggestion in dictionaries)

Comment: Can you use Cut off your nose to spite your face, and Throw out the baby with the bath water? Both bad ideas.

Comment: Is this an idiom suggesting it's a bad idea, or something saying it's a worthwhile sacrifice? There's also *["Kill them all; let God sort them out."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caedite_eos._Novit_enim_Dominus_qui_sunt_eius.)* or *[nuke it from orbit](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nuke%20it%20from%20orbit)* although they're not quite idioms.

Comment: There are similar questions here which might help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592328/what-will-the-the-idiom-or-phrase-for-to-cross-the-river-without-making-feet-wet/592330 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431532/a-phrase-for-something-that-is-sacrificed-as-a-side-effect-of-process/431645 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345636/what-is-a-synonym-for-the-idiom-to-make-an-omelette-you-have-to-crack-a-few-egg/345655

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this Biblical reference would be easily understood in English.

Depending on the context, the nearest English idiom might be "cut off one's nose to spite one's face":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_off_one%27s_nose_to_spite_one%27s_face